# How to get multiple options from a Materialize drop down menu to automatically query an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, materialize, apex

I'm working on a project where the user can pick from a list of states from a dropdown menu I got from Materialize and the goal is for it to then query the National Park Service Data API and pull information about parks in their states. However, I'm having issues getting the user's selection to automatically query the API or even with a submit button. The dropdown list works and allows users to select multiple states and then click off and click submit but nothing happens. Thanks in advance for help.

```
 <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper" id="searchid">
<div class="section no-pad-bot">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row center">
      <img src="search.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax"><img src="b15.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 2"></div>
```

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <select multiple>
        <option value="" disabled unselected>Choose your state</option>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
        <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
        <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
        <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
        <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
        <option value="FL">Florida</option>
        <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
        <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
        <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
        <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
        <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
        <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
        <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="ME">Maine</option>
        <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
        <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
        <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
        <option value="MT">Montana</option>
        <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
        <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
        <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
        <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="UT">Utah</option>
        <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
        <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
        <option value="WA">Washington</option>
        <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
      <label>Search</label>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
var apiKey = "kjVPCM3LEwQYZxkv4byFPo1TRCvJk61IAO9wwtyI";
var searchTerm = "";
var stateTerm = "CA";

var queryURL = "https://api.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?q=" + searchTerm + "&stateCode=" + stateTerm + "&api_key=" + apiKey;
console.log(queryURL);


var parkName = "";
var parkDescription = "";
var parkLatLon = "";
var parkURL = "";

$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET"
}).then(function(response) {

    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
      parkName = response.data[i].fullName; 
      $("#test-results").append("<li>" + parkName + "</li>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Give an id to `<select>` tag in order to get the values from dropdown.

```
<select id="states" multiple>
    <option>.....</option>
    .
    .
    .
</select>
```

2.) Give an id to `<button>` tag in order to handle click event. Add an event to button with the help of `addEventListener`.

```
<button id="subBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
```

**Complete working code:**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select id="states" multiple>
            <option value="" disabled unselected>Choose your state</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
        <label>Search</label>
        <button id="subBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('subBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let states = document.getElementById('states');
    let options = states.options;    //To get all the options present in <select>
    let selectedStates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].selected) {    //If option is selected then push it inside the array
            selectedStates.push(options[i].value);
        }
     }
     console.log(selectedStates);
     const apiKey = "kjVPCM3LEwQYZxkv4byFPo1TRCvJk61IAO9wwtyI";
     let searchTerm = "";

     //Loop through all the selected states to get the queryURL
     for (let i = 0; i < selectedStates.length; i++) {
         let stateTerm = selectedStates[i];
         var queryURL = "https://api.nps.gov/api/v1/parks?q=" + searchTerm + "&stateCode=" + stateTerm + "&api_key=" + apiKey;
         console.log(queryURL);

         $.ajax({
             url: queryURL,
             method: "GET"
         }).then(function (response) {
             console.log(response);
         });
     }
 });
```